# HTML5 Canvas Drawing in Real Time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, typescript

**Question:** How can I make `putImageData()` update the canvas in real time, as various parts of the image have been computed?

---

I am working on a JavaScript/TypeScript application to draw the Mandelbrot set on an HTML5 `<canvas>` element. Math and details aside, my application draws the set just fine. However, if you are familiar with visualizing the set, you know that it can take a long time to draw.

It will draw in a few seconds, but until then, the canvas is completely blank, then the image appears. I'm looking for a way to draw each row as it is computed using `putImageData()`. Here is what I am trying:

```
// part of the class definition
private Context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
private ImageData: ImageData;
private Pixels: number[];

constructor() {
    var c: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("can");

    this.Context = c.getContext("2d");
    this.ImageData = this.Context.createImageData(this.Size.Width, 1);
    this.Pixels = this.ImageData.data;
}

public draw() {
    // tried this... does not help
    // var handler = function(m: Mandelbrot) {
    //    m.Context.putImageData(m.ImageData, 0, i)
    // };

    for(var i: number = 0; i < this.Size.Height; ++i) {    // Loop over each row
        for(var j: number = 0; j < this.Size.Width; ++j) { // Calc px. for one row
            // all the math to compute the set... (works)

            this.setPixelColor(j, color); // sets a color in this.Pixels (works)
        }

        // setTimeout(handler(this), 0); // does not help
        this.Context.putImageData(this.ImageData, 0, i); // Draw the row on the canvas?
    }
}
```

Somehow, the `putImageData()` function, which is called after a row in the image has been computed, only shows the image after the entire image has been generated.

How can I make `putImageData()` update the canvas in real time, as each row has been computed?

---

Latest update of non-working code:

```
var handler = function(m: Mandelbrot, i: number) {
    for (var j: number = 0; j < m.Size.Width; ++j) {
        // math

        m.setPixelColor(j, color);
    }

    m.Context.putImageData(m.ImageData, 0, i);
};

var that: Mandelbrot = this;

for(var i: number = 0; i < this.Size.Height; ++i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        handler(that, i)
    }, 0);
}
```

---

Working code, thanks to ekuusela:

```
var handler = function(m: Mandelbrot, i: number) {
    return function() {
        for (var j: number = 0; j < m.Size.Width; ++j) {
            // math

            m.setPixelColor(j, color);
        }

        m.Context.putImageData(m.ImageData, 0, i);
    }
};

for(var i: number = 0; i < this.Size.Height; ++i) {
    setTimeout(handler(this, i), 0);
}
```

Comment: The solution would be complex, but the basic response is that JavaScript is single-threaded and runs on the UI thread; so while any code is running, nothing new will display. Most JavaScript logic can run very quickly so this isn't an issue, but the Mandelbrot set would probably be a candidate for a setTimeout-based solution, or web workers (Web Workers are pretty complex)

Comment: the row that calls the setTimeout also executes the handler, you could for example wrap the handler(this, i) in a function or make handler(this, i) return a function.

Comment: @ekuusela Thank you. I've applied your function wrapping idea, which now yields no output. Sounds like this feature might just have do go. JS, you've done it again.

Comment: Try returning a function from the handler instead? I think i now always has the same value when the handler executes. (Don't make functions within loops)

Comment: @ekuusela Sorry, nut how do you return a function in JS?

Comment: `var handler = function(...) { return function() {...}; };`

Comment: @ekuusela Whoa! You are genius! That totally worked! Thank you, thank you, thankyou thankyou thankyouthankyou...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping `putImageData` and the calculation for a single row to a `setTimeout` call to execute it asynchronously (post accept edit: see the final code in the question, this won't work since `i` will be `undefined` in the `putImageData` row)

```
public draw() {
    var that = this;
    var drawRow = function() {
            for(var j: number = 0; j < that.Size.Width; ++j) { // Calc px. for one row
                that.setPixelColor(j, color); // sets a color in this.Pixels (works)
            }

            // TODO specify the dirty region in this call
            that.Context.putImageData(that.ImageData, 0, i); // Draw the row on the canvas?
        };
    for(var i: number = 0; i < this.Size.Height; ++i) {    // Loop over each row
        setTimeout(drawRow, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, and it didn't work, and crushed my CPU. I updated my question to reflect that attempt.

Comment: I've updated my answer, did you try something like that, i.e. the entire calculation and drawing of a single row in the same async function? You could also try requestAnimationFrame to lessen the impact on CPU

Comment: I just gave that a shot, and I still end up with the same result. Actually, it is a bit slower than without the `setTimeout()`, as a result of the function call overhead. :(

Comment: Hmm, the picture comes up all at once at the end? You could try specifying the dirty parameters as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData

Comment: Did you use my code example or the one commented out in your post? My one has different part wrapped in the timeout callback

Comment: It is more like the latest update you have, with the separated callback function.

Comment: Updated, as requested.