# Javascript - plot in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fractals

I've created a Mandelbrot Set plotter, and it uses the HTML Canvas element.

```
 var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

However, this means that it doesn't render until all the calculations have been done, and this can take some time.

I'd like to use a "real-time" plotter - i.e. one that shows each "pixel" as it's plotted.  Back in the day, when using QuickBasic (for example), this happened immediately, and so one would see the "scanlines" as the code computed each pixel.

I've googled around, but all I've found are "charting" tools, like Flot or Pusher.

PLEASE can somebody suggest some pixel-plotting tools that I can use?  JQuery, Javascript, whatever (client-side, obvs).

Thanks :)

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/robinmckenzie/sh5tqcze/6/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas Drawing in Real Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732995/html5-canvas-drawing-in-real-time)

Comment: A further (unrelated) question: why, when setting `maxIterations` to 17, is the colour rendered as magenta, at 27 it's grey, and at 37 it's green?  I must have missed something obvious here, but I can't figure it out...?

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks, that's really helpful, and *exactly* the same as the query I've just made!  The setTimeout solution seems complic, though.  Any ideas on a non-Javascript way of achieving what I'm after?

Comment: A zoomed-in version here: https://jsfiddle.net/robinmckenzie/sh5tqcze/8/